# I have used JSR223 post processor to fetch data from request body in jmeter but i am facing error

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

```
String requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
String BatchName = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX).parseText(requestBody).params.BatchName
vars.put('BatchName', BatchName)
log.info('BatchName: ' + BatchName)
```

I have used the above code but i am facing the below error :

> Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got
> current char 'o' with an int value of 111 The current character read
> is 'o' with an int value of 111 expecting '}' or ',' but got current
> char 'o' with an int value of 111 line number 1 index number 1

I was expecting to fetch BatchName from request of a sample to use it in further samplers

Answer (score 0):

The "below error" means that your request body is not a valid JSON, you can check it yourself using i.e. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Your script also missing necessary [imports](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_simple_import)

In general extracting something from **request** is a very strange type of activity because it's **you** who makes the request, I could understand extracting data from response or generating it, but fetching something from request indicates that most probably your test plan is badly designed. If you're going to use a piece of data in more than one place it makes sense to declare it in [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)